# Alternative to MS Acess for in-house user database

Tags: security, data-integrity

I am a working student at a bank and my current task is to create an in-house database for customer-specific lookups which often rely on complex underlying data aggregation from different sources. I was expecting to get access to something like a SQL Server or similar in order to implement this but was left with the challenge to do it without a dedicated DB or server to work with. My goal is to implement the most sustainable solution and not do something like a quick'n dirty fix.

I am always up for a challenge but certain things like **data security/integrity and multi-user access popped** up when I thought of implementing it all **with MS Access**.
On top of that I worry that it might become messy and also cause some drama should I eventually leave the company.

There are of course dedicated things like an **Oracle Data Warehouse** but using this will be problematic as other departments **are denied access to it** and therefore will not be able to use it.

Next thing that came to mind was using something like a portable DB. I downloaded **PostgreSQL** Portable and it works great, but since I am pretty much the **only one fluent enough in SQL to use it**, it would require some kind of frontend like Access yet again.

To outline my situation: I have **access to my own computer** and **Network Storage with daily backups**. I, as for now, do **not have the ability to leave my laptop on all the time** and have no access to a dedicated server.

On top of being a DB, I would like it **to update and load data from other sources at regular intervals**, but I could also automate that via PowerShell scripts if needed.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is using something like MS Access a smart or rather stupid idea? Are there any points I was missing in my assessment?
2. Are there any free alternatives I could use for my needs?
3. Is the plan in its current state even doable or should I rather sit down and negotiate about access to more resources?

I know that the questions are more subjective than I would like but I don't want to upset our DBA's and I think most of you guys have faced similar situations and know what would have been a far better solution.
I appreciate any input.

Comment: What exactly does it need to do? You say "customer related look ups." I could do that in Excel.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, edited my answer. It needs to be a portable ETL/DB, although that sounds like a unicorn that sh*ts gold. It is less about the things it needs to do, but rather the multitude of things it should be able to do and the aspect of portability.

Comment: I guess I am trying to figure out why you need a DB at all. Excel is very portable and you can connect to different data sources and load data in it.

Comment: That is totally true, but for one I have faced multiple situations where I just downright was not able to use excel since I passed the row limit by multiple millions and secondly because I am trying to aggregate many different sources of data into different structures and having many excels files and having to update them by hand is a tedious process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the free [SQL Server Express Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express), and use Access or many other tools as a front-end.  You can take nightly backups to network storage, or even store the database files directly on the network storage device.

Later the database can be migrated to a enterprise-managed SQL Server with no code changes.